# Theorem style and Design

Tags: theorems

I have seen in a few books a style for theorems of the form

[image]

So what I want ideally is a the theorem title at the top and then the whole theorem enclosed in a box. The shadow is not needed but would also be nice to have. Would anyone know how to produce this?

Comment: See package `tcolorbox`

Comment: Also see package `mdframed` http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf